# Is it possible to access variables in frontend memory?

Tags: javascript, frontend, client, websecurity

If I have some code that runs in when a user lands on my page, such as `const num = Math.random()`.

Is it possible for the user of the website to access the value of that variable, given that it is now in memory on their local machine? Should it generally be assumed that data in memory on the client is no longer secure?

Comment: Yes, anything in memory on the client can be viewed and modified using Developer Tools. That's how you debug the application, isn't it?

Comment: Where can that be viewed? I can see basic things, such as react useState variables which assign a value to an HTML input, but I don't know where variables and their associated values are located.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the middle of a function, then you can view all the local variables of the function.

Comment: You can see variables in the sidebar, in Scope->Global and Scope->Local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The user can open the developer tools and put a breakpoint in the code after that assignment happens and inspect the value there.

If the value is stored in a global, persistent variable, then they could examine it from the console at any time.

EDIT: not only can the user *see* the value, they can *change* the value as well. This is why you can never trust any client data sent to your server code, even if that data was generated by your JS code. The user could have modified it before it was sent.

Comment: Do you know where in the dev tools I can interact with the JS code my client receives? And could you elaborate what you mean by the second part? If we can add a breakpoint after assignment, can we not do that for any variable (global or not), and examine it whenever the relevant code runs?

Comment: In Firefox you can set breakpoints in the dev tools under the "Debugger" tab. In Edge it's the "Sources" tab. In both of those browsers, the Console tab will allow you to just start typing global variable names and helpfully auto-complete them. Once you've got the full variable name, hit enter and it will print the value.

Comment: And if you're in a breakpoint, you can also type local variables. The console is basically acting in the scope where the program is stopped.